# How to handle incorrect formatted requests in an API

Tags: java, spring, api, exception

I am wondering what the correct way is to handle this type of request. I have a delete requests from a UI and it's a list of ID's which are integers. So the request can look like :

```
www.myui.com/delete/1,2,3,4
```

which is a well formatted request. But if the request for any reason came from a curl request or postman etc it may be formatted like:

```
www.myui.com/delete/1,,3,4
```

In this case the 2nd index will contain null since it's inspecting Integers. However if we were expecting a list of String it would be simple an empty string or an n amount of white space characters if it was formatted like /1,   ,2,3, 4, so I would have to loop through the request and check if a string in the list of string is only white space and throw back a 404.

Should I be doing this in the controller or allow this type of request to pass on by and have the eventually have the exception thrown in the dao since it's going to try and delete an id that is either null or just white space which won't exist in the DB.

Below is an example of how I am currently handling the request which is a List of Integers.

```
@DeleteMapping(value="/delete/{ids}")
    public ResponseEntity delete(@PathVariable("ids") List<Integer> ids)
            throws DatabaseException {
        if (ids.contains(null)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        service.delete(ids);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, fail fast is a better approach as it helps detect malfunctioning very early and quickly, although you might also consider business requirements and general design guidelines of your application, if it should be lenient, then you might go with something like:

```
service.delete(ids.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

and return a response body containing at least a number of items deleted.

If your application has to be strict, then a bad request should be returned as soon as possible as you are already doing.

Also, you have to take in consideration that your services and/or DAOs are not exclusively called from controllers, so validations and/or checks have to be implemented there as well, and try not to let malformed requests hit the database if you already know they would lead to errors, it would be just wasted traffic.

Finally, I hope the integer ids in your case are not DB generated, in which case it would be a major security issue since you are exposing persistence details over your api, an attacker could just wipe out your database or parts of it by just sending list of incremented integers. I would suggest you use some kind of randomly generated unique ids to expose over the api (this does not mean that you should get rid of integer base indices).

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to handle the errors as soon as you detect them. In this case, the bad request is detected at controller level so it is the best option to handle it there.

Though your approach is fine, looking at `@ResponseHandler` may be instructive, as it can be used to generalize the handling of known exceptions, on `Controller` level.